Looking for the title of a thriller movie about a killer among a group of friends
A group of people/friends are getting killed by traps set up by the villian one by one and they suspect each other being the killer. It is similar to Mind-hunters but in this movie the killer fakes his death so he doesn't seem like the suspect, I think he does this by walking into a shop and setting off the trap which freezes him instantly. Which later he gets out of and continues to kill the other people but reveals himself when there are 2 people left aiming a gun at each other, blaming one another.
Any help been trying to look for this movie for so long, I seen this maybe 10 years ago. The movie was atleast before 2008.

Do you remember any of the other traps the killer used? Was the freeze trap liquid nitrogen like Mindhunters?

OK, this is not a clean fit, but there is enough to merit a posting here (I hope). The answer could be one the adaptations of Agatha Christie's book And Then There Were None. Movies by that name were released in 1974, and 1945. Adaptations named "10 Little Indians" were released in 1989, 1965, and 1959 (1 hour short).
Where it doesn't fit:

I don't think the killer gets frozen in any of these (I could be wrong)

Where it does fit:

They are getting killed one by one
They suspect each other
The killer fakes his own death
The killer reveals himself when only two are left
There is a gun being pointed between the last two survivors while "blaming each other"

Before going on, I should mention that there was a 2015 mini series, and a Russian adaptation that was faithful to the book (from what I could gather). 
The 1989 (10 Little Indians) adaptation was set in an African safari:

Rehash of classic Agatha Christie story about 10 people who believe they have won a trip to go on an African safari, but are soon killed off one by one by an unknown murderer.




The 1974 (And Then There Were None) adaptation was set in the Iranian desert:

Ten people are invited to a hotel in the Iranian desert, only to find that an unseen person is killing them one by one. Could one of them be the killer?




The 1965 (10 Little Indians) adaptation was set in a snowy mountain:

Up to a house high on a mountain top have been invited ten people who are strangers to each other. When they are all gathered, they hear from their host that each one of them has in someway caused the death of an innocent person and that justice had not be served in their cases. There are eight guests and two servants there for the weekend, but one by one, they are being knocked off according to the poem of "Ten Little Indians". As the number of survivors decreases, they begin to believe that the killer is one of the group, but are unable to decide on which one he or she may be.




The 1959 (10 Little Indians) adaptation was set in an isolated island:

Live television presentation of Agatha Christie's famous work "Ten Little Indians". A group of amoral people are invited to an isolated island mansion. Upon arriving, a recorded phonograph message accuses them of certain crimes in which they could not be touched by the law. After one dies from poison, another from an overdose of sleeping pills, a third from being struck/falling into a fire, and a fourth from stabbing, (all according to the ten little Indians nursery rhyme) the remaining number realize the killer is among those present. In the desperate game to survive, the remaining number try to figure out who the killer is, before they are murdered. Who will be next?




The 1945 (And Then There Were None) adaptation was set in an island off the English coast:

Ten people are invited for a weekend on an island by a Mr U. N. Own, but he isn't on the island. At dinner a record is played, by that all the people are accused of murder, suddenly the first of them is dead, then the next... It seems to be that one of them is the murderer Mr. U. N. Own, but the person in suspect is always the person who is murdered next. At last only two people seem to be left. 





It's kinda simular to Steel Trap actually, the movie was also before 2008 and I found it when I was watching Mind-Hunters. You should look for it.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

Nothing else I can't remember which i havent wrote

Did you look Steel Trap?
